# Loss first decreases and then increases

Tags: nlp, bert, transformer

I am using pre-trained `xlnet-base-cased` model and training it further on real vs fake news detection dataset. I noticed a trend in accuracy for first epoch. Accuracy increases till some point (approximately half) of first epoch and then decreases. Loss also first decreases and then increases rapidly (it is not Nan). What can be reason of this trend ?
I noticed same trend when I tried to run it with `roberta-base`. But any such trend was not noticed when I trained with `distilbert`, accuracy goes on increasing in this case.

Here is graph for accuracy VS steps:
[image]

[EDIT]
File containing running output of the model:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r5AWftyHTLf5sqtgWnQm_4lqB84UrJex/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this the loss on training set or validation set?

Comment: It's the training set loss that is decreasing, if I see it right, @AshwinGeetD'Sa

Comment: Are you sure? This kind of situations are possible on training loss, but they are mainly associated with validation loss.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa yes its on training set.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa I have also added a file link where you can see detailed output of running model.